# How do I grab, sort and display top commenters (PHP/MySQL)?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting

Its been two days and I still can't figure this out: how do I retrieve all the users who commented on a given article, sort them in descending order by the number of times they commented and then display their username and number of times they commented (i.e., michael (17), laurie (14), jenny (10), dennis (6), etc.)?

Comment: What does your database structure look like for the tables in question?

Comment: **[What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)**

Comment: You really have to provide more information than this.  And as previously stated, YOU have to tell US what you have tried.

Comment: `$query = $CI->db->query('SELECT users.username, comments.user_id FROM comments, topics, users WHERE topics.topic_id='.$topic_id.' AND comments.topic_id='.$topic_id.' AND comments.user_id=users.user_id ORDER BY comments.user_id DESC');`

`$contributors_data['rows'] = $query->result();`


`foreach ($contributors_data['rows'] as $r) {
$contributors_count_data = array('username' => $r->username, 'user_id' => $r->user_id);
}`

`$contributors_count_data = array_count_values($contributors_count_data);`


`return print_r($contributors_count_data);`

Comment: sorry for the mess, I don't know how to get line breaks in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the database structure, it's hard to say. But assuming it's something like this:

**Article**

- Id
- Content

**Comments**

- Id
- ArticleId
- UserId
- Comment

The query would look something like this:

```
SELECT UserId, COUNT(*) as CommentCount FROM Comments WHERE ArticleId = 1 GROUP BY UserId ORDER BY CommentCount DESC;
```

Then you'll just need to do a `JOIN` on the user table to get the user's name.